# Getting data from a QTreeWidgetItem inherited class

Tags: linux, qt, kde-plasma, treewidget

I have a class which inherits from QTreeWidgetItem and I intercept the click event.

I need to get another object from inside MY QTreeWidgetItem when I click the tree row, how can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create and add the item:

```
newItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(myExplorer);
```

set the data:

```
newItem->setData(myListWidgetItem::idType, 1234);
```

And have a slot that accepts the item clicked (on the tree), which you can read the data from:

```
connect( myExplorer, SIGNAL( itemClicked (QTreeWidgetItem *, int) ), this, SLOT( slotFillListWidget(QTreeWidgetItem *, int) ) );
```

Comment: Initially I assumed that you would intercept the signal from the Tree Item, however after further reading I see that getting the trees clicked signal is what you really need.

Comment: ok, I can put my data but I can't read it because it becomes a QVariant data. How can I cast from QVariant to Pkg? (Pkg is the object that I put into the treewidgetitem)